# C Program that stores an unknown number of strings of unknown sizes from user - Heap block at 00558068 modified at 00558096 past requested size of 26

Tags: c, string, heap-memory, block, realloc

I'm trying to write a program in C that takes an unknown number of strings (each of unknown size) from the user as input and stores them then prints them when the user has finished entering strings.

First I use a pointer that points to character pointers (char** strings) and allocate 1 char* sized block of memory to it with malloc. I then allocate 1 char sized block to the pointer that strings is pointing to ( *(strings) ) with malloc also. From there I take a string input from the user using a user-defined function called get_String() and place it into the char pointer that char** string is pointing to. I then use a for loop to continue allocating an extra char* of memory to char** strings and 1 char of memory to the new pointer.

However, I keep experiencing an error on the 2nd iteration of the for loop, on the line strings = (char**) realloc (strings, index+1); and I receive the error message: Heap block at 00558068 modified at 00558096 past requested size of 26. It seems like I am writing past the allocated memory to char** strings, but I don't know where or how I am doing this.

Here is my entire code:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "stdlib.h"

void get_strings( char* strings); // function to take in a string of an unknown size

int main( void )
{
    char** strings;
    int index, count;

    (strings) = (char**) malloc( sizeof(char*)); // this is the pointer that holds the addresses of all the strings
    *strings = (char*) malloc( sizeof(char)); // the address of the first string

    printf( "Enter a list of stringss. Quit by pressing enter without entering anything\n" );

    get_strings( *strings );

    for( index = 1; strlen(*(strings+index-1))!=1; index++) // stores strings from the user until they enter a blank line which is detected when string length is 1 for the \n
    {
        strings = (char**) realloc (strings, index+1); // adds an extra character pointer for another string
        *(strings + index) = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)); // allocates memory to the new character pointer 


        get_strings( *(strings + index) ); // stores the string from the user
    } 

    printf( "You entered:\n" );

    for( count = 0; strlen(*(strings + count)) != 1; count++ ) //prints every string entered by the user except for the terminating blank line
    {
        printf( "%s", *(strings + count ) );
        free( *(strings + count ));
    }

    free( strings );


    system( "PAUSE" );
    return 0;
}

void get_strings( char* strings )
{
    fgets( strings, 1, stdin ); 

    while( strings[ strlen( strings ) - 1 ] != '\n' )
    {
        strings = (char*) realloc( strings, strlen(strings)+2 );
        fgets( strings + strlen(strings), 2, stdin ); 
    }

}
```

As stated before, heap block occurs  on the second iteration of the for loop while executing the line: strings = (char**) realloc (strings, index+1);

```
for( index = 1; strlen(*(strings+index-1))!=1; index++) // stores strings from the user until they enter a blank line which is detected when string length is 1 for the \n
    {
        strings = (char**) realloc (strings, index+1); // error occurs here
        *(strings + index) = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char)); // allocates memory to the new character pointer
```

I would very much appreciate it if someone could explain to me the cause of this error and a direction to fix it. Thank you.

Comment: You should do some debugging to find out why.

Comment: The usefulness of this: `*(strings + index) = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char));` is *highly* questionable. Your `get_string` should *return* the dynamic address of its acquired string, and said-address should be assigned in your pointer array (the indexing of which is likewise *highly* questionable). Best of luck.

Comment: Have you looked at C++? There classes such as std::vector and std::string makes it almost trivial to write this kind of code.

Comment: 1)`fgets( strings, 1, stdin ); ` : It is substantially invalid because it does not save the input.

Comment: 2)`strings = (char*) realloc( strings, strlen(strings)+2 );` : It is substantially invalid because it is not reflected in the caller.

Comment: 3) should be like this : `strings = (char**) realloc (strings, (index+1)*sizeof(char*));`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *get_strings(void);

int main( void ){
    char **strings = NULL;
    char *string;
    int index, count;

    printf( "Enter a list of stringss. Quit by pressing enter without entering anything\n" );

    for(index = 0; string = get_strings(); ++index){
        strings = (char**) realloc (strings, (index+1)*sizeof(*strings));
        strings[index] = string;
    }
    printf( "You entered:\n" );

    for( count = 0; count < index; ++count ){
        printf("%s\n", strings[count]);
        free( strings[count] );
    }
    free( strings );

    system( "PAUSE" );
    return 0;
}

char *get_strings(void){
    char *string = NULL;//or calloc(1,sizeof(char)) for return "" (test by caller: *string == '\0')
    int ch;
    size_t len = 0;

    while(EOF != (ch=fgetc(stdin)) && ch != '\n' ) {
        string = (char*)realloc( string,  len + 2);//To realloc to each character is inefficient
        string[len++] = ch;
    }
    if(string)
        string[len] = '\0';
    return string;//The value is NULL when there is no input substantial.
}
```